# ¿Existe algo similar a background-image en NavBar de Material-UI con react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar, material-ui, background

Buenas noches estoy desarrollando un ToDo App en react con material-ui, y quiero que mi Navbar tenga una imagen de fondo, pero no encuentro una propiedad para hacerlo, ¿saben si existe alguna propiedad para hacerlo?
Aquí coloco el código de mi componente, esperando me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {AppBar, Toolbar, Typography, makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    offset: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    root: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    toolbar: {
        minHeight: 128,
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        paddingTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    title:{
        flexGrow: 1,
        alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    },
}));

const Navbar = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position='static'>
                <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <Typography className={classes.title} variant='h2'>
                        MI DÍA
                        <Typography className={classes.subtitle} variant='h6'>
                            Fecha
                        </Typography>
                    </Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
                <div className={classes.offset}></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: En react las clases tienen que ponerse de forma distinta. Todas existen solo que no puedes usar el guión medio. ¿Has intentado usar `backgroundImage` en lugar de `background-image`?

Comment: Muchas gracias, si ese era el error, ya pude cargar la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

En react puedes asignar una imagen de fondo como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<div style={{ 
     backgroundImage: `url("https://via.placeholder.com/500")` 
}}>
```

Un saludo